# Regular expression for xpath in selenium java code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

Selenium java code for regular expression.

Xpath = `"//*[@id='gritter-item-6']/div[2]/div[2]/p"`

In above xpath `6` is varying, any one help me how to solve this problem

Please give me the solution for this.

Comment: Can you paste some of the html, containing the element(s) you're trying to match?

Answer (score 6):

Try using the below xpath where we use `contains` keyword.

```
//*[contains(@id, 'gritter-item-')]
```

Comment: I would be very careful with this approach because it can easily match any other ID that has the same format. And assuming this is a auto generated ID I'd say the possibilities that this is true are pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more accurate, you can use `starts-with()` instead of `contains()`, since your IDs are starting with specific string.

You can use : `//*[starts-with(@id, 'gritter-item-')]`

Comment: Note that funcions like `starts-with` and `ends-with` are XPath 2.0 specific. If you're using Selenium's Firefox WebDriver, for instance, it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, what helped me was to install Selenium IDE and extract the "Xpath Position" the position is not dynamic as long as the button does not change the position on the page. Hope that this helps you.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZD26.jpg)