# Looking for same xpath for grid's column text from two different pages

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

In our application, there is a situation where there is a grid on two pages. I want to get text of columns from the grids. But both grid's column text has little different HTML.

**Page 1 grid HTML:**

```
<div class="ngHeaderContainer" ng-style="headerStyle()" style="width: 598px; height: 30px;">
  <div class="ngHeaderScroller" ng-style="headerScrollerStyle()" ng-header-row="" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="ngHeaderCell ng-scope col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ height: col.headerRowHeight }" style="height: 30px;">
     <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" ng-style="{height: col.headerRowHeight}" style="height: 30px;"> </div>
      <div ng-header-cell="">
        <div class="ngHeaderSortColumn " ng-class="{ 'ngSorted': !col.noSortVisible() }" ng-style="{'cursor': col.cursor}" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="true">
          <div class="ngHeaderText ng-binding colt0" ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-click="col.sort($event)">Request ID</div>
```

For this, I've written xpath `//div[@class='ngHeaderContainer']//div[@ng-header-cell='']//div[contains(@class,'ngHeaderText')]`

**Page 2 grid HTML**

```
<div class="ngHeaderContainer" ng-style="headerStyle()" style="width: 598px; height: 30px;">
  <div class="ngHeaderScroller" ng-style="headerScrollerStyle()" ng-header-row="" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="ngHeaderCell ng-scope col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-style="{ height: col.headerRowHeight }" style="height: 30px;">
     <div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" ng-style="{height: col.headerRowHeight}" style="height: 30px;"> </div>
      <div ng-header-cell="">
        <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-click="onColumnClick( 3, 'select', $event)">
        Request ID
         <img class="" ng-click="onColumnClick( 3, 'delete', $event)" src="styles/images/common/delete.png" ng-show="true">
<img>
</div>
```

For this, I've written xpath `//div[@class='ngHeaderContainer']//div[@ng-header-cell='']/div`

For grid, I've written a class and in that class I've method which returns column names. Since, xpath till reach to column name is different for grid on two different pages, I won't be able to use same method.

Can someone please help me to get xpath which can be used to return column names of the grid of both the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath will do it hopefully. I ran into similiar issue. Took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293632/regular-expression-for-xpath-in-selenium-java-code). This should return you both elements

//*[contains(@class, 'ng-binding')]